# MongoDB aggregate $lookup returning the whole collection instead of an empty list

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate, lookup

These are my schemas:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FavoritesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true,
    },
    movieId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    genre: {
        type: [String]
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String
    },
    dateAdded: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
        index: true
    },
});

FavoritesSchema.index({ userId: 1, movieId: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model.Favorites || mongoose.model("Favorites", FavoritesSchema);
```

For some reason when I switch the localField and foreignField values, instead of returning an empty list, it returns the whole favorite collection.

```
const userData = await User.aggregate([
            { $match: { username: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6488dbc8628dcd80e771192b") } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'favorites', // Assuming 'favorites' is the collection name
                    localField: "userId",
                    foreignField: "username",
                    as: 'favorites',
                },
            },
        ]);
```

I tried adding adding different users but still nothing

Comment: You're saying that when you write the $lookup in such a way that specifies nonexistent fields from both collections then all the results are returned? I'd guess that is expected behavior since a missing value from one doc "matches" a missing value from the other

Comment: Please include some sample data and a sample response that you are getting.